# Get a table cell value where I have a checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m new in JQuery and I have a trouble. I want to read a specific cell value from a table row where I have a checkbox. I have an event that handles the checkbox checked event. This is my code:

```
$("#businesses input:checkbox").change(function (
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {

            //Here I want to read a value from a column in a row where is the checkbox

        } else {
            //Here I want to read a value from a column in a row where is the checkbox 
        }
});
```

I have a table called "businesses" and it has this format

```
<table id="businesses">
<tr>
  <th>Select Value</th>

  <th>Value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectedService" title="Seleccionar" /></td>
  <td>125</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectedService" title="Seleccionar" /></td>
  <td>126</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do, is that when I select a checkbox, get the value field of its row.

If I press the first checkbox I want to get 125.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `$this.parent().next().text()`. Read more about DOM traversal: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your checkbox (`this` in the event handler function), you need to go up to the containing `<td>` element, across to the next `<td>` element, then get its text:

```
$('#businesses input:checkbox').change(function(e) {
    if(this.checked) {
        var value = parseInt($(this).closest('td').next('td').text(), 10);
        // above will convert it from a string to an integer
    }
    else {
        // same as above? Seems redundant
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!. I am doing two different operations with the values. It works

Comment: @Cesar_K-rrillo In that case, get the value out *before* the `if` statement, and simply use it in different ways in your conditional branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `siblings()` of the parent:

```
$this.closest('td').siblings().text();
```

If this is not the only other `<td>` `siblings()` would return all of the rest so use appropriate selector to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

You could access it with:

```
$this.parent().next().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#businesses input:checkbox").on ('change', function (e)
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $( e.target ).closest("td").text();
        } else {
            //Here I want to read a value from a column in a row where is the checkbox 
        }
});
```

Greetings.